# Implementation of unique_ptr

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I'm trying to understand how `unique_ptr` works inside. I found a simple implementation. Please tell me what the constructor does.

```
template<typename T, typename D = default_delete<T>>
class unique_ptr {
public:
    using pointer = T*;
    using element_type = T;
    using deleter_type = D;
 
unique_ptr(pointer p, 
        typename std::conditional<std::is_reference<deleter_type>::value,
            deleter_type, const deleter_type&>::type d) noexcept
    : _impl{p, d}
    { }
 
private:
    detail::Ptr<T, D> _impl;
```

Comment: _"Please tell me what the constructor does."_ - I have a potentially better idea: why don't you tell us which parts of the constructor you're having trouble understanding...?

Comment: Why is used typename std::conditional<std::is_reference<deleter_type>::value,
            deleter_type?  Why can't I use  explicit unique_ptr(T* raw_resource)?

Comment: The constructor isn't really doing that many things. Are you asking what the `std::conditional` business in the parameter list, what's happening with the initialization of `_impl` in the member initializer list, or both?

Comment: I don't understand the meaning of this expression. Why is this?

typename std::conditional<std::is_reference<deleter_type>::value,
            deleter_type, const deleter_type&>::type d)

Comment: [std::conditional<Condition, TrueType, FalseType>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional) is a struct whose member type `type` is defined based on whether `Condition` is `true` or `false`. So, if `std::is_reference<deleter_type>::value` is true, the type of the argument `d` is `deleter_type`. Otherwise, the type is `const deleter_type&`.

Comment: Perhaps you want to look at `make_unique()`  to understand it better.

Comment: I understand what std::conditional<Condition, TrueType, FalseType> does. I don't understand why this is needed.

Comment: It is needed because [the specification of `std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr) say it must be so.